# fsockopen не хочет соединяться по https

Tags: php, сокет, https

Вызов функции

```
$hole = fsockopen("https://217.ххх.ххх.ххх:81/History/HistoryService.asmx", 81, $errno, $errstr, 10);
```

ведет к ошибке

> (Unable to find the socket transport "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?)

Вопрос: где конфигурируется поддержка https-протокола в socket, к провайдеру обратиться или настройки в своих файлах надо сделать какие-то?

Comment: немного неправильно выразился, мне нужно послать запрос по этому адресу и получить обратно xml-данные, не могу создать соединение по https. 

fsockopen("217.ххх.ххх.ххх", 81, $errno, $errstr, 10) - сервер выдает ошибку, говорит, что я обратился обычным text/plain-запросом к https

Answer (score 2):

> [fsockopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php)
>
> **hostname**
> If OpenSSL support is installed, you may prefix the hostname with either ssl:// or tls:// to use an SSL or TLS client connection over TCP/IP to connect to the remote host.

```
$hole = fsockopen("ssl://217.ххх.ххх.ххх", 81, $errno, $errstr, 10);
```

Разумеется, OpenSSL должен быть установлен

Comment: Спасибо, OpenSSL установлен на удаленном сервере. Может, я вообще неправильно думаю, сейчас сформулирую иначе:
Есть сервер, на который мне периодически нужно отправлять данные в нижеприведенном формате. В примере все работает, но я не знаю, как правильно сделать обращение такое же из скрипта:

http://www.bertal.ru/index.php?url=https%3A%2F%2F217.117.65.147%3A81%2FHistory%2FHistoryService.asmx&ar=239110#h

Comment: В мануале по ссылке выше есть куча примеров.
Но судя по всему вам не нужна низкоуровневая работа с сокетами. Используйте лучше [cURL][1]

А так же почитайте про [SOAP][2] и соответствующее [расширение для PHP][3]. 

  [1]: http://ru.php.net/curl
  [2]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP
  [3]: http://ru.php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php

Comment: Используйте curl

http://php.net/curl

Answer (score 1):

эм ... у вас ваще бред написан.
Если вы хотите получить контент по этому адресу то используйте

```
file_get_contents("https://217.ххх.ххх.ххх:81/History/HistoryService.asmx");
```

Если вам нужно соеденится именно через сокеты, то нужно писать:

```
$hole = fsockopen("217.ххх.ххх.ххх", 81, $errno, $errstr, 10);
```

Comment: fsockopen("217.ххх.ххх.ххх", 81, $errno, $errstr, 10) - сервер выдает ошибку, говорит, что я обратился обычным text/plain-запросом к https

Comment: ну дык, правильно, наверное. Вы же не привели ту часть где вы "общаетесь" с сервером, да и нету смысла на сокетах писать "общение" с ssl

Вы скажите зачем вам это ?